# Two ways of optimize the same function?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, logistic-regression

I'm actually reading [this tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/logreg.html#logreg) about deepLearning and in particular about Logistic Regression.

I don't get why it first says to optimize logistic regression taking the max Probability and after using the Log loss function ?

Sorry you can explain me the point where him will use the Argmax and where Will use the Loss ?

you would not need only 1 of this 2 ?

Answer (score 2):

The argmax is to get the class label prediction y_pred given a sample x.

`# symbolic description of how to compute prediction as class whose 
 # probability is maximal
 self.y_pred = T.argmax(self.p_y_given_x, axis=1)`

The Loss function is used as optimization objective function to solve the coefficients W and b based on training data. On the tutorial, the loss function is the reverse the likelihood.

Comment: Worth reinforcing that the `argmax` function is *not* used to optimise anything - it is not really possible, because it is not differentiable. Instead it is being used to output a predictive value that we are interested in. There are ways to use it if for instance we want to meta-search parameters - then we might use accuracy on a cross-validation data set as a metric for the search.

Comment: @Xing Wang in the testing phase you don't get as output only 1 predicted value? why i have to do argmax ?

Comment: @NeilSlater sorry meta serach you mean build a tree of possibile paramteres and get the best parameter ? and you want build this graph using the output of a cross-validation ?

Comment: @Xing Wang i m not sure as ouput you get a vector of value and after you make the argmax ... in the testing phase i suppose to give a value and get as output 1 value... i dont get your point. After i learned all the W parameters after i should have as ouput a value.

Comment: @T-student: Not usually a tree, but a vector of numeric options where you do not know how to set them to get best generalisation from your model. In logistic regression your search space for meta params is likely to be low dimensions, maybe just the single value for a regularisation param. So you would likely do a very simple search for the best accuracy (or F1 score, or logloss, or area under ROC, whichever metric you think best represents good solutions to your problem) using a cross-validation set, and just try a range of regularisation param values, training for each one in turn.

Comment: @T-student Could you explain how you get a vector of value after the argmax?  Code snippets are welcomed. For the test phase, you could see the predict function in the whole code http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/logistic_sgd.py. The predict function receives 10 samples, and give the predict value for each sample.

Comment: @William: The OP's code is processing a matrix of all predictions for a data set. So it is taking argmax in one axis only, and ending up with a vector of class labels - one for each example input vector in the dataset. In other words, it's processing a batch.

Comment: To: NeilSlater. Thank you for the explanation on @T-student 's question.

Comment: @William the optimization part i think will output W matrix and b.  after this your test is just doing  x*W + b = y   ... y is your output vector where you need to use the argmax ? :S